# Set Dynamic Height of UIView and UIScrollView

Tags: swift, dynamic, uiview, uiscrollview, height

I want to make a UIView's height equal the content that is inside of it. How do I do this? Here's my storyboard

```
View Controller
  Scroll View
    View //The view that needs to have dynamic height
      UILabel
      UIButton
      UIView
```

So, I need to make the View to have dynamic height because the height of the elements inside the view change height on certain circumstances.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: @CoolPenguin No